# How to avoid code duplication with very similar JUnit4 tests

Tags: android, kotlin, junit

I have several JUnit4 tests, in different modules, that look almost identical (following 3 examples of many dozens):

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `GIVEN AccountNotFound from getAccessTokenInteractor WHEN call invoke THEN returns UnrecoverableError Failure`(): TestResult = runTest {
        // Given
        coEvery { getAccessTokenInteractor() } returns Err(GetAccessTokenInteractor.ErrResult.AccountNotFound)

        // When
        val response: Result<NotificationsQuery.Notifications?, GraphQlCallError> = getNotificationsInteractor()

        // Then
        response.unwrapError() is GraphQlCallError.UnrecoverableError
    }
```

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `GIVEN AccountNotFound from getAccessTokenInteractor WHEN call invoke THEN returns UnrecoverableError Failure`(): TestResult = runTest {
        // Given
        coEvery { getAccessTokenInteractor() } returns Err(GetAccessTokenInteractor.ErrResult.AccountNotFound)

        // When
        val response: Result<Unit, GraphQlCallError> = updateNotificationInteractor(1)

        // Then
        response.unwrapError() is GraphQlCallError.UnrecoverableError
    }
```

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `GIVEN AccountNotFound from getAccessTokenInteractor WHEN call invoke THEN returns UnrecoverableError Failure`(): TestResult = runTest {
        // Given
        coEvery { getAccessTokenInteractor() } returns Err(GetAccessTokenInteractor.ErrResult.AccountNotFound)

        // When
        val response: Result<Int?, GraphQlCallError> = getUnreadNotificationsCountInteractor()

        // Then
        response.unwrapError() is GraphQlCallError.UnrecoverableError
    }
```

The only part that is changing is the `response`, that is always unwrapped to the same `GraphQlCallError.UnrecoverableError` (the "Given" and "Then" part are identical).

What's the best way to avoid all this code duplication?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to accept a lambda that generates the response:

```
fun testResponseIsUnrecoverable(
    responseLambda: () -> Result<Any, GraphQlCallError>
): TestResult = runTest {
    // Given
    coEvery { getAccessTokenInteractor() } returns Err(GetAccessTokenInteractor.ErrResult.AccountNotFound)

    // When
    val response: Result<Any, GraphQlCallError> = responseLambda()

    // Then
    response.unwrapError() is GraphQlCallError.UnrecoverableError
}
```

Then your three tests could be reduced to:

```
@Test
fun `GIVEN AccountNotFound from getAccessTokenInteractor WHEN call invoke THEN returns UnrecoverableError Failure`(): TestResult =
    testResponseIsUnrecoverable { getNotificationsInteractor() }
```

```
@Test
fun `GIVEN AccountNotFound from getAccessTokenInteractor WHEN call invoke THEN returns UnrecoverableError Failure`(): TestResult =
    testResponseIsUnrecoverable { updateNotificationInteractor(1) }
```

```
@Test
    fun `GIVEN AccountNotFound from getAccessTokenInteractor WHEN call invoke THEN returns UnrecoverableError Failure`(): TestResult = runTest {
    testResponseIsUnrecoverable { getUnreadNotificationsCountInteractor() }
```